# Forks of MIT licensed projects

Tags: open-source, mit-license

Let's take an example:

> #### User A
>
> MIT license
>   Copyright (C) 2014, User A

> #### User B
>
> other license (not MIT) in which people who
>   fork won't require mention of the current copyright notice
>   Copyright (C) 2014, User B & User A

> #### User C
>
> any license
>   Copyright (C) 2014 User C
>   (No link with User A because User B's license did not require mention)

- User A releases a JavaScript library under MIT license. The first line of the license contains :

  `Copyright (C) 2014, User A`.
- User B forks the project (with a new name) and his new own license. **1st question: What does he need to write ?**

  `Copyright (C) 2014, User A and User B` ?

  or

  `Copyright (C) 2014, User B
  (original author: User A)`  ?

  **Moreover**, let's say User B's license (not MIT) **doesn't contain** `The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.` **anymore** (this was present in User A's MIT license).
- User C forks User B's project. As User B's new license does not contain the previous sentence (`The above copyright...`), then User C has no link with User A's license. Is that right ?

  **2nd question : Is it mandatory for User C to mention User A?**

  **It seems that in that story, User A's wish (his copyright notice to be included in forks) is not respected.**

Answer (score 3):

To quote from [MIT license text](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT):

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> **The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.**

Anyone who distributes this code must include the license.  So if B forks from A, B must include the license.  B may not remove the license restrictions without A's permission, so if C forks from B, C must also abide by these license restrictions.

In other words, in your question, B is violating the license terms and thus may not legally do this.

(Of course, I am not a lawyer.  Please consult one if you need to do such things.)

Comment: C might have removed all of A's parts from B thus C might not contain stuff copyrighted by A anymore. But that's quite a specific case. It's most likely an oversight of C, not any kind of bad intention.

Comment: Thanks @StevenBurnap. About 1st question, how should User B write its copyright ? `Copyright (C) 2014, User A and User B` ? Another way?